# Trying to install composer

Tags: php, curl, mamp

I am running my application in MAMP server. I want to install composer.
I tried to doing this by this command.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

But, it's giving me error.

> `#!/usr/bin/env php`
>
> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script
>   again:
>
> The detect_unicode setting must be disabled. Add the following to the
>   end of your `php.ini`:
>
> ```
> detect_unicode = Off
> ```
>
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /private/etc/php.ini If
>   you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d
>   option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple
>   times.

What could be the reason. This command consider default PHP installed in mac or it's going to targer MAMP's PHP?

Comment: Have you ***read*** the message?!

Comment: How to change the path for MAMP php ? I don't know, that's why I put whole error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either follow the instructions and edit the php.ini file as it says, or don't use `php`, which is the system's PHP installation, but use the full path to MAMP's PHP instead:

```
$ curl ... | /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php<your-version-here>/bin/php
```